# Match object inside object in jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I'm testing a function to see if, when called, it will return the proper created list.

- To start, I create the elements, using the `createDesign.execute()` functions. It's tested on another file and working.
- Then, I call the function I want to test: `listAllDesigns.execute()` and store it's value in a variable.
- If I `console.log(list)`, it returns the full list properly.

In pseudocode, what I'd like to do is: Expect `list` array to have an element with the `design` object and, within it, a `design_id` that equals `"payload3"`.

How should I write this test?

Is there a better way to do this? (other than checking if list !== empty, please)

```
  it('should return a list of all designs', async () => {
    // Create fake payloads
    const payload1 = {
      ...defaultPayload,
      ...{ design: { ...defaultPayload.design, design_id: 'payload1' } },
    };

    const payload2 = {
      ...defaultPayload,
      ...{ design: { ...defaultPayload.design, design_id: 'payload2' } },
    };

    const payload3 = {
      ...defaultPayload,
      ...{ design: { ...defaultPayload.design, design_id: 'payload3' } },
    };

    await createDesign.execute(payload1);
    await createDesign.execute(payload2);
    await createDesign.execute(payload3);

    const list = await listAllDesigns.execute();

    // expect(list). ????
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method would be a combination of `expect.arrayContaining` and `expect.objectContaining` like so:

```js
expect(list).toEqual(
    expect.arrayContaining([
        expect.objectContaining({
            design: expect.objectContaining({
                design_id: "payload3"
            })
        })
    ])
);
```